# Need to Understand How To Deploy in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, tfs, branch

Recently my company has decided to switch to one Main branch, instead of a having the incremental branches of Dev, then Test, Stage etc.

Previously, we would check in code in Dev, kick off the Dev build, and the build would drop the files to the file location for Dev. We'd then merge up to Test and do the same thing.

Now, since we're going to have just one Main branch that still deploys to Dev, yet still need the code to eventually progress its way up to the Test and Stage environments, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood. Are you saying there will only be a single branch, and that it will be named "Main"? That sounds like someone doesn't understand branching.

Comment: The strategy will be to have the Main branch of code. Then, when working on an iteration, the team branches off of that main, completes a body of work, merges the branch back into main, and archives the previous branch. This way, we're ensuring that all of the code that is going into our Dev Test Stage and Prod environments is the same. We would then perhaps publish or deploy the code up to Test, for QA. I just don't know how the proper way to do the deployment to another environment without a build.

Comment: Very bad idea. See the [ALM Rangers Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Based off of the ALM Rangers Branching guide, we're already doing the "Standard" branching plan, and it has landed us in a spider web so vast due to developers not adhering to standards, that we're looking to do what the ALM Rangers call the "Basic" branch plan.

Comment: The "Basic" plan doesn't involve creating a branch for each iteration. You could use labels for that, but not branches.

Comment: Correct. We are wanting to have 1 branch called Main. The Standard plan calls for creating a branch for each environment. We're looking to simply deploy from Main, to the various environments.

Comment: It's not a branch per environment. It's a branch for each situation where you might have to do simultaneous development that's isolated from the other branches. There's a RELEASES\RELEASE branch not as the place to deploy from, but as the place to do final, release-breaking fixes. There's a "Service Pack" branch so that you can work on developing a service pack at the same time as you're working on the next major version in the DEV/DEV branch.

Comment: Alright. So how can I deploy one build to more than one environment without building for each of those environments? I just want to build once, then deploy individually to each environment as the business is ready. Thanks.

Comment: I used to have this issue. I wanted to deploy _the exact same bits_ to the various environments. The bits that passed QA were the ones to deploy to Production. But, if you can trust your builds to be consistent and reliable, you no longer need this restriction. In particular, different builds _of the same exact code_ can produce different (transformed) config files, different parameters for IIS and other servers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer for [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster), I can say that the product was designed to solve this exact problem space. It may be free depending on your specific use-case.

Because BuildMaster is platform independent, you'll need to grab the TFS extension once you've installed it from the Extensions page.

If you're interested, check out the introduction webinar we did a few weeks ago to see what it's all about: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9Sk3koazLg. It also solves about 1000 other issues you may encounter with the automation process, but that can be saved for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Release Management for Visual Studio (previously called InRelease). It supports what you are looking for and it works with 2012 and 2010 as well.

You should to build once and store the artifacts and then use the same artifacts to deploy to other environments.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx